# AJAX response empty on phone, but correct on desktop browser test

Tags: javascript, cordova

So I have a server that is hosting a PHP file that looks like this:

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
?>
Testing, testing
```

Then I have an AJAX request on my PhoneGap index file in a document ready that looks like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        type       : "GET",
        url        : "http://example.com/PhoneGap/test.php",
        crossDomain: true,
        success    : function(response) {
            alert("\""+response+"\"");
        },
        error      : function() {
            alert('Not working!');
        }
    });
```

But whenever the app starts (on Android) all that pops up is an alert window that contains "". However, when I run the index page on my desktop browser, I get "Testing, testing", which is what I expect.

So, anybody know what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

[Solved] The issue I was having was that I did not whitelist my domain in the config.xml file. This was solved in the comments of this post, so there is no post marked answer, just read through the comments if you're having this issue and you'll see how it was resolved.

Comment: No, `alert` works fine on phonegap. I've alert'd many other things and they all appear fine.

Comment: Try removing `crossDomain: true`.

Comment: I actually have another AJAX request that's basically the same as the previous but without crossDomain: true and it does the same thing :(

Comment: Another thing that comes to mind: don't you have to list all target domains on the config xml file on phonegap? See http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html

Comment: Is res/xml/cordova.xml a file I have to create? It doesn't seem to be in the project.

Comment: If it doesn't exist, try creating it. I only used it on iOS, which is a little different.

Comment: Oh, the guide you linked me to was older. I'm using PhoneGap 3.0.0 which, I guess, is now abstracted to the main config.xml. But yeah, that seems like it was the problem. Thanks a ton! :D

Comment: Ah, I googled too fast! Glad to know you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using JSONP - cross domain Ajax is terribly unreliable. Perhaps the WebKit in Android doesn't support the cross domain flags.